# Symmetric Polynomials: Binomial identity

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, polynomials, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Consider the following equality of symmetric polynomials of degree $n$:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}c_ix^iy^{n-i}+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}c_i(x+y)^iz^{n-i}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}c_iy^iz^{n-i}+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}c_ix^{i}(y+z)^{n-i}$

(We set $c_0=c_n=0$ and $c_i=c_{n-i}$.)

Now how can one see that (after comparing coefficients on both sides) we get for
the coefficients of $x^{\alpha}y^{\beta}z^{n-\alpha-\beta}, \alpha >0, \alpha + \beta <n$,

$c_{\alpha + \beta} \binom{\alpha + \beta}{\beta}=c_{\alpha}\binom{n-\alpha}{\beta}$?

Comment: Hint: where do terms of the given form come from on the left-hand side? How about on the right-hand side? Just write down the corresponding summand in each case and the answer should pop out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all exponents are positive we have general terms
\begin{eqnarray*}
LHS = c_i  \binom{i}{j}x^{i-j}  y^jz^{n-i}
\end{eqnarray*}
and 
\begin{eqnarray*}
RHS = c_I x^{I} \binom{n-I}{n-J} y^{n-I-J}z^{J}.
\end{eqnarray*}
This gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
i-j&=&I&=&\alpha \\
j&=&n-I-J&=&\beta \\
n-i&=&J&=&n-\alpha-\beta.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now solve these ($j=\beta,i=\alpha+\beta,n-I=n-\alpha,n-J=n-\alpha-\beta$)
and we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
c_{\alpha+\beta} \binom{\alpha+\beta}{\beta}=c_{\alpha}\binom{n-\alpha}{n-\alpha-\beta}
\end{eqnarray*}
the second binomial coefficient is the same as is stated in the question by symmetry of binomial coefficients.